# Android Custom listview Item Turning grey after click

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, onclick, onclicklistener

I have android listview with custom adapter.I have implemented the AdapterView.OnItemClickListener . Onclick it launches a new fragment. Now all of that works, but the listview Item turns grey after click in the background.I need it to be transparent/white.
So I thought it must be in a selected state which I somehow have to disable. 
This is what I have tried so far without any luck.

> listview.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
>
> listView.setFocusable(false);
>
> listView.setActivated(false);

Other options such as

> in onItemClick(){
>   view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),
>   android.R.color.transparent));

interesting this seems to be **semi working** as if I use color.red. I can see it getting red momentarily before the fragment dialog shows at that point I can see it turning grey again in the background.

Also the **odd** part is that this last piece of code i.e

> view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),
>   android.R.color.transparent)

works in onItemLongPress. And it stays transparent as expected.